# pdflush on port 80 preventing Apache from restarting

Tags: linux, apache, centos, plesk

Preliminaries:
+ CentOS 5
+ Plesk 10.4.4 Update #35

Problem: During the addition/alteration of a new domain/host in plesk, it will normally write new or update apache vhost config files and then restart the apache service. The updating rewriting seems to go fine, there are no errors in the files, however lately apache fails to restart after shutting down due to the unavailability of port 80, further examination via "netstat -tulpn..." shows the following...

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      25794/PDFLUSH
tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      25794/PDFLUSH
```

You can see that PDFLUSH is occupying a high process ID but is sitting on both 80 and 443 which prevents apache from coming back up.  I'm having to manually get the PID and issue a kill before I can run "service httpd start" again to get apache up.

In my searching, I've seen an old reference to someone being hacked but I can find any similar symptoms, and honestly I don't know what to look for in the logs or which log file to look at specifically.  I've also heard that this could be a symptom of failing memory but I don't know how to test memory on a production server.

Please, any help would be greatly appreciated, my heart sinks every time I get an SMS that the servers down again!

---

EDIT
It's happened again by simply adding a subdomain, however this time I was able to run a ps -aux quickly prior to killing the PDFLUSH instance and bringing back up apache...

> apache   ...   ./PDFLUSH -b service.config

Trying to search out the location of that now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news is I found the culprit, the bad news is that it is "c99", just do a google on it and you'll find a long history.  Now the real fun begins, has the server been rooted?

For those that have similar issues and think it might be the same even if it's using a name other than "PDFLUSH", just do a

> find /var/www/vhosts -name PDFLUSH

To figure out where the little bastard is hiding.  I found mine in one of my shared hosting clients sites buried deep in a dir tree inside the webroot.

Answer (score 0):

The `netstat` output that you have included is highly suspect:

- The program that you are seeing is called `PDFLUSH` with all characters in upper case. This seems like an attempt to evade detection; `pdflush` (all lower case) is the name of a legitimate kernel thread that handles writing dirty memory pages back to the disk. It highly unlikely that any legitimate program would be using such a name.
- The legitimate `pdflush` does not have any networking capabilities - it has nothing to do with networking at all. This one seems to be acting as a web server, yet no web server with such a name exists. Unless you explicitly installed a custom web server with that unfortunate name, you have a problem.

  Have you tried connecting to those two ports with `netcat` or a Telnet client? That might give you a clue on what is going on.

As far as testing the memory of your system goes, [`memtest86`](http://www.memtest.org/) is the de facto standard tool these days. Failing memory, though, usually appears in the form of random crashes - what you are seeing seems way too specific.

Comment: That was my suspicion but I've found it hard to get any other background info on this type of incursion (at least using PDFLUSH in the search), I've only seen one reference and it was somewhat old. Because this is a production server, it's kind of time sensitive when it goes down to get it back up, so I haven't taken any time to poll the ports.  Are there any log files you can possibly point me to that would contain any relevant start or stop details for the service, something that might point to the location of the service files?

Comment: Wou you *trust* any log files that you see?

Comment: Ok, well short of wiping out the server and starting from scratch, how would one go about identifying the little bastard?  Are there not system protected log files that it wouldn't be able to manipulate?  I have root access disabled, limit SSH access to specific IP's, only use strong passwords and don't allow connections to the server without SSL, so short of guessing my passwords and spoofing my ip's, I can't imagine that they've been able to get too far.... could they have?  Anyhow, suggestions would be appreciated, all we've done so far is agree, it's likely a hack of some sort.

Comment: @oucil: 1. There *are* local root exploits, you know. 2. There are also misconfigurations that can lead to a root compromise. 3. There is nothing safe from a process with root privileges - SELinux *may* offer some degree of protection by curtailing root's capabilties, but I doubt that any distribution would do that by default. 4. What does `ps` have to say about `PDFLUSH`? What user is it running as? Because, as far as I know, a process cannot bind to the lower ports (< 1024) without root capabilities...